# ScrollView not able to scroll at all

Tags: android, scrollview

I have looked through similar questions and not looking for generalize answers but rather want to know why my below code is not working. I am generating the rest of the child inside LinearLayout programmatically. The only issue is that it is not scrolling. Please find below the code for the bottom-most card.

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/card2"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="1dp"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/scrollview">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/parentScroll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" />
</ScrollView>
```

Please find below the screenshot how it looks like. The scroll view should allow me to scroll for remaining future days in the bottom-most card but it only shows what fits on screen with no scrolling.

[image: in]

Comment: There won't scroll If the UI component height is not over ScrollView height

Comment: ScrollView only enables scrolling when it just needs to (i.e. when there is no more space on the screen to occupy elements wrapped in the ScrollView)

Comment: @GuanHongHuang please see the updated question. It is actually more than UI component height.

Comment: @Zain please see the updated post. It needs more space :)

Comment: try to add bottomToBottom-to-parent constraint and scrollview to android:fillViewport="true"

Comment: @Nik same issue :(

Comment: Set the scrollView height to match_parent

Comment: @DevendraSwami scrollview height is match parent?

Comment: I have already tried by putting first it into viewgroup linear layout and then setting scrollview height to match_parent. I can't do it simply as then it will mess up with other 2 cards

Comment: Quick solution : add a fixed height to scrollview like 250dp..

Comment: tried that too :( . This is my first android app really stuck.

Comment: add  android:animateLayoutChanges="true" in your linear layout and scrollview

Comment: @Nik no help. Even now I am trying to remove all child, set a height greater than viewport, but still no scrolling :(

Comment: @DevendraSwami - in above my instruction to set bottom constraints to parent. Have you try to set height android:layout_height="wrap_content" to android:layout_height="0dp" ?

Comment: thanks @Nik. It worked. I would love to accept it as an answer. You gave the best thanksgiving to me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding bottom constraint to scrollview `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"`and change `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` to `android:layout_height="0dp"`

Answer (score 0):

There is no resource in your view. The code should work if you try this:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/card2"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="1dp"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:background="@drawable/scrollview">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/parentScroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/long_string"  <-- Add a long string
        android:orientation="vertical" />
</ScrollView>
```

Add you string resource in `res/values/strings.xml` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <string name="long_string">
      real really long text      <-- Add Text Here
   </string>
</resources>
```

Comment: I am generating resource programmatically. Please see the updated post.